# Parse specific date string format

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have read a lot of questions and searched for a lot of libs all over the internet but I can't find one that can do this quickly.

I want to parse a specific date in a specific date format like this:

```
String date = "20130516T090000";
SimpleDateFormat x = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddTHHmmss");

String theMonth = x.parse(date, "M"); // 05
String theMonth = x.parse(date, "MMM"); // MAY
String theMinute = x.parse(date, "mm"); // 00
String theYear = x.parse(date, "yyyy"); // 2013
```

Just simple as that. A way to set a Parse Rule, a Specific Date Format and a way to retrieve each data i want (Month, Minute, Year....)

Is there a good library to do EXACTLY this? If yes could you put an example together? If no, is there a good way to do this without much code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse a date from a `String` to a `Date` instance.

   ```
   String date = "20130516T090000";
   SimpleDateFormat x = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

   Date d = x.parse(date);
   ```

   There was a problem in your `SimpleDateFormat` format String, text in the format has to be quoted using single quoted (') to avoid interpretation.
2. Use the `Calendar` class to get the part of the date you want.

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(d);

   String theYear = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
   String theMonth = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
   String theMinute = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
   ```