# Parsing and converting Datetime format from csv file to mysql in Java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, csv

I have a csv file in which the Datetime column is defined in "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM" format. But the problem is MySQL accepts Datetime type as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" only. I want to convert the format given in csv file to format defined by MySQL but I am not able to do it.I tried to covert the format in excel but first there is no datetime format in excel and if I split the column into two then it changes the structure of my file and thus not able to insert in database.So, the only option is to use Java program and change the format before inserting.
Can anyone provide me some help in this regard?

This is my class which is getting called for converting the formats but I do not know what is wrong here and whether it is sufficient or I am missing something.(This class is getting accessed from another program.)

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DateUtil {

    // List of all date formats that we want to parse.
    // Add your own format here.
    private static List<SimpleDateFormat> 
            dateFormats = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        {
//            add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy"));
//            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy"));
//            add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
//            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
//            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"));
        }
    };

    /**
     * Convert String with various formats into java.util.Date
     * 
     * @param input
     *            Date as a string
     * @return java.util.Date object if input string is parsed 
     *          successfully else returns null
     */
    public static Date convertToDate(String input) {
        Date date = null;
        if(input == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        for (SimpleDateFormat format : dateFormats) {
            try {
                format.setLenient(false);
                date = format.parse(input);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //Shhh.. try other formats
            }
            if (date != null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return date;
    }

}
```

Comment: Excel .. Java .. whoa? Pick one :) Either *fix* the (CSV) data first in Excel (such that it is "correct" when Java handles it) or correctly deal with it in Java. Java has no problem parsing such a date time format into a Date object, which can then be used with MySQL (and really, should be inserting dates, not strings into a datetime column!). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598650/parse-specific-date-string-format and similar.

Comment: csv file had data in "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM" format and I want to convert it to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM".

Comment: Stop thinking about strings. Convert the `String` into a `Date` (e.g. using `SimpleDateFormat` with the appropriate format) and then pass the `Date` as as parameter to the applicable MySQL insert code. The database driver will in turn take the `Date` and insert it as the appropriate `DATETIME` type in the database. (But if you wanted a `String`, then you could create one [with the applicable format] from a `Date` object.)

Comment: @user2864740 please see the edit in above post.I have tried SimpleDateFormat but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you could change the format through the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
public static String dateConvert(String origFormat) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat origDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    Date retrivedDate = origDateFormat.parse(origFormat);
    return newDateFormat.format(retrivedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have an csv file with a column of date but stored as String in format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM" and you want it to be formated as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" to make mySql happy.

If yes, why don't you just use excel to do the job:

- Add new column in the file, for example:

  Date DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM  | Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

  01-02-2013 23:59       | 2013-02-01 23:59

The newly added column will have this formula "=MID(A2,7,4)&"-"&MID(A2,4,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2, 2)&" "&RIGHT(A2,5)"

- Now your new column has date stored as string in the desired format, just copy the column to notepad, then copy from notepad back to paste on the first column
- Delete the new (second one) column and save your file as csv again.

Comment: I tried to do it this way but the output is beyond comprehension. Actually in the text if at the 7 position is 2 of 2013 then it is reading 9 which is no where present throughout the text.

Comment: Can you put here a representative sample of your data, I believe we can solve it just by excel

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `SimpleDateFormat` class - you can use that to parse the incoming text as a Date.

Comment: I tried SimpleDateFormat but I am not able to get success.Please check the edit above in the post.

Comment: The date format looks correct.  Can you write a bit of code to use the date format directly (not via the util class) and copy/paste a date from the csv, and let me know what happens?  Specifically I want to know if there are any exceptions.

Comment: i tried to debug it and the problem is that it is not getting converted into the required format.Basically it returns  null to the program which is calling this class.So, with this null it throws exception as the format is not supported

Comment: @user2916886 You probably have something wrong in the format you're reading from the CSV.  Can you copy and paste one entire line of that file as a comment here?

Comment: this is the first line of the csv file- "2013-01-01 21:56:29"

Comment: You left out the seconds in your format, and you set lenient to false, so SimpleDateFormat won't parse it.  Try yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.